# Resize UIImage to have 512 x 512 resolution and keeping size less than 100 KB in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

How can I resize UIImage to have 512 x 512 resolution and keeping size less than 100 KB. I am successful to achieve the required resolution but size is always more than 100 KB.

Answer (score 1):

You could compress the image using `jpegData(compressionQuality:)` method to achieve size less than a particular value using this extension:

```
extension UIImage {

    func jpegData(sizeLessThan sizeInKB: Double) -> Data? {
        var compressionQuality = CGFloat(1)
        var compressedData = jpegData(compressionQuality: compressionQuality)
        while (Double(compressedData?.count ?? 0) / 1024) > sizeInKB && compressionQuality >= 0 {
            compressionQuality -= 0.1
            compressedData = jpegData(compressionQuality: compressionQuality)
        }
        return compressedData
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var image: UIImage?
let imageData = image?.jpegData(sizeLessThan: 100)
print(imageData)
```

Comment: I need this image in png